# Create Qt Pro 'QWidget' does not name a type Q_DISABLE_COPY(QWidget)

Tags: c++, qt

I use Qt(5.6.1) creator(4.0.3)in Unbuntu16.10，I create a simple Pro,without adding any codes .but many Problems occur.the code below here:
Test.pro:

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = Test
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        widget.cpp

HEADERS  += widget.h

FORMS    += widget.ui
```

widget.h

```
 #ifndef WIDGET_H
 #define WIDGET_H

#include <QWidget>
namespace Ui {
class Widget;
}

class Widget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Widget(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Widget();

private:
    Ui::Widget *ui;
};

#endif // WIDGET_H
```

widget.cpp

```
#include "widget.h"
#include "ui_widget.h"

Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Widget)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

Widget::~Widget()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

the problems like this:
[problems](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1yMdh.png)

Comment: Show your `.pro` file. Possible, you forgot to add WIDGET module.

Comment: I have post it in the Question @Dmitry Sazonov

Comment: seems like your compiler doesn't correctly deal with `QWidget(const QWidget&) = delete` try to add `CONFIG += c++11`. Also, don't post screenshots of error messages, just copy the messages as test